# MongoDb Update only one value from array

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb, laravel, jenssegers-mongodb

I have a collection in **mongodb** which looks like this.

```
"_id" : ObjectId("554c5397ccfff21e103c9869"),
"name" : "test",
"color" : [
    "552ced22ccfff2d8183c986a_Jellow",
    "551fdd24ccfff2362e3c9869_test"
],
"updated_at" : ISODate("2015-05-08T06:11:35.303Z"),
"created_at" : ISODate("2015-05-08T06:11:35.303Z")
```

I want to update only one value in the array **color** But when i try to update the array it removes all the values from the color array and replaces it by the new value.
Here is the code. (**I AM USING JESSENGER MONGODB PACKAGE FOR LARAVEL**)

```
$query->where($field,'regexp','/^('.$id.')_.*/')->update([$field=>$id.'_'.$name]);
```

How should i do it.??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you wanna do is, either change your schema as {key: value} pair and then follow this [tutorial](http://mongoblog.tumblr.com/post/21792332279/updating-one-element-in-an-array), that will help you to sort out your problem. **OR** you can get all the values from color array and replace with new value and then update your document (I would not go for it coz it is a dirty approach!).

**EDIT**

Hey Bud! I founded this, on jenssenger docs:

---

## Push

**Add an items to an array.**

```
DB::collection('users')->where('name', 'John')->push('items', 'boots');
DB::collection('users')->where('name', 'John')->push('messages', array('from' => 'Jane Doe', 'message' => 'Hi John'));
```

If you don't want duplicate items, set the third parameter to true:

```
DB::collection('users')->where('name', 'John')->push('items', 'boots', true);
```

---

## Pull

**Remove an item from an array.**

```
DB::collection('users')->where('name', 'John')->pull('items', 'boots');
DB::collection('users')->where('name', 'John')->pull('messages', array('from' => 'Jane Doe', 'message' => 'Hi John'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `$set` operator. Not sure how it's done in Jessenger Mongodb, but it might be something like:

```
$query->where($field,'regexp','/^('.$id.')_.*/')
      ->update(['$set' => [ $field=>$id.'_'.$name]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't change your data like this:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("554c5397ccfff21e103c9869"),
"name" : "test",
"color" : [
    { "id":"552ced22ccfff2d8183c986a", "name":"Jellow"},
    { "id":"551fdd24ccfff2362e3c9869", "name":"test"}
],
"updated_at" : ISODate("2015-05-08T06:11:35.303Z"),
"created_at" : ISODate("2015-05-08T06:11:35.303Z")
```

then you can update element by id.

Comment: I cant change the schema... :(